# Node JS https hosted on bluehost

Tags: node.js, ssl, https, webserver, bluehost

I have a dedicated VPS through bluehost, hosted on it is my node.js project. As of now I can use app.listen(80) so that anyone who navigates to my url will get my ejs to correctly display to them, however the web browser shows the "not secure" message to the left of the url. I'm trying to get https working so that a web hook can send data to my web server. The other program that sends the web hook data requires an https address not http. I know that bluehost has built in SSL but I'm not sure how to use this in tandem with a node.js app. It seems to work fine if I publish just a simple HTML page. I've tried creating a self-signed certificate with openssl and using the following code

```
 const options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('key.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('cert.pem')
};

https.createServer(options, function (req, res) {
   res.writeHead(200);
   res.end("hello world\n");
}).listen(8000);
```

But chrome refuses to accept the certificate when I navigate too mydomain.com:8000, additionally I'd prefer to find out how to set it up so that mydomain.com defaults to https, not http like it is doing so now. Thanks in advance for any advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up finding that the BlueHost autoSSL files are stored at /home//ssl/ and you can read in both the *.key and *.cert files from there. The file paths don't change when the cert renews and it's signed by a proper CA instead of self signed so chrome and other browsers will actually accept it! Hope this helps someone else